# How to force Google Cloud Shell to comply to system keyboard layout?

Tags: google-cloud-shell, keyboard-layout

I'm using a TypeMatrix 2030 external keyboard, with bépo layout set system-wide on my Ubuntu 20.04. Everything works fine, in each and every app I've used since I own this keyboard (approx. 5 years ago).

However, I'll be using a lot Google Cloud Shell from now on, and it doesn't comply to my system settings. Some keys work, others don't.

For what it's worth, « Alt is Meta » doesn't help, nor defining Alt Gr key position from Cloud Shell settings.

Here is an example, for better understanding, showing behavior differences on all rows (without mod keys):

- on system layout (valid)

```
$"«»()@+-/*=%
bépoèdljzw
auie,ctsrnm
àyx.k’qghfç
```

- on Cloud Shell (mostly invalid)

```
`'<9456=-/0=5
bwpotdljzw
auie,ctsrnm
zyx.knqghf/
```

From what I understand, it seems that some keys comply with system layout, and others are like on « forced qwerty layout », specifically the `w` and `z` which matches qwerty layout position.

I didn't include examples with mod keys but, as you could guess, there's also issues with them.

Comment: Have you already followed the debian documentation[1] to change the keyboard layout? 
Cloud Shell runs a debian-based OS[2]. Furthermore I would not recommend setting up a dev environment on Cloud Shell because it is pre-configured and ephemeral. If anything goes wrong, you may need to restart Cloud Shell and this can erase the changes not only of the keyboard layout but also from other packages installed. 
[1]https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard#How_to_switch_a_keyboard_layout_in_X11_.2F_graphical_desktop_environment_or_ttyX_console
[2]https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works

Comment: @AntonioRamirez The command setxkbmap is not available on Google Cloud Shell. However, the issue also appeared with VMWare web console, so it is not related to Google Cloud Shell.
It works as expected with Firefox and GCloud Shell / VMWare console, but not with Chrome ! So I guess it’s a Chrome bug.
I didn’t try with other Chromium-based browsers yet.
Thanks for your reply anyway :)